# Writing Java constructor for child class that takes parent object

Tags: java, class, constructor, parent

Is it possible to use a parent object to instantiate a child object? The class Length2 extends Length1 with the addition of an instance variable. Common I tried to make a copy constructor that takes the Length1 as a param and sets the extra ivar to 0, but I'm still being told I cannot convert from Legnth1 to Length2. I suppose there may be some implicit casting taking place... have a look.

```
public class Length1 extends Length implements Comparable<Length1>{

    protected int miles;
    protected int yards;

    public Length1(){ //default constructor
        miles = 0;
        yards = 0;
    }

    public Length1(int m, int y){ //constructor
        miles = m;
        yards = y;
    }

    public void setYards(int x){
        yards = x;
    }
    public void setMiles(int x){
        miles = x;
    }
    public int getYards(){
        return yards;
    }
    public int getMiles(){
        return miles;
    }
```

...

```
public class Length2 extends Length1 {

    protected int feet;

    public Length2(){ //default constructor
        super(0,0);
        setFeet(0); 
    }
    public Length2(int m, int y, int f){ // constructor
        super(m,y); 
        setFeet(f); 
    }
    public Length2(Length1 x){ 
        super(x.miles,x.yards);
        setFeet(0); 
    }
    public void setFeet(int x){
        feet = x;
    }
    public int getFeet(){
        return feet;
    }
```

...

```
public class LengthTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Length1 a,b,c,d,e,f;
        Length2 g,h,i,j;

        a = new Length1(78,1610);
        b = new Length1(77,1694);
        c = new Length1();
        d = new Length1();

        g = new Length2(32,1022,1);
        h = new Length2(31,1700,2);
        i = new Length2();
        j = new Length2();


        j = c; //problem occurs here


    }

}
```

Comment: well, that's how inheritance works. if L2 is more specific than L1, you can't say that some L2 = L1 because L2 needs to know some information about fields that are specific to L2 that are not present to L1.

Comment: of course, you can create some L2, then say it's an L1 and then try to say it's L2 again. To do this, you have to cross your fingers and perform a casting operation

Comment: Is there a work-around where I could write a method to cast the object? I only need the two ivars contained in the L1 object to be copied to the L2 object. Yes I know that it doesn't make much sense practically :/

Comment: Usually, when you want to convert one object into another, you use what we call the "adapter" design pattern. http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-uncovered-0

Comment: If you don't want to get into this interfaces mess from the article, you could create a method at L2 called "valueOf(L1)" that would copy all the compatible information from L1 into L2, assuming that specific information that only L2 knows would be missing.

Comment: sorry, this may not be the adapter pattern. Maybe some sort of a factory pattern, whatever. I'll leave this terminology to something else :-) but I think you've got the idea

Comment: You can't `j = c` unless you do some casting. You should try `j = new Length2(c)` as it's already defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Length2 IS A Length1, so you can always assign a `Length2` *object* to a `Length1` reference (you never have to cast it). You can also assign a `Length1` reference that points to a `Length2` object to another reference declared as `Length2`. In this case you need an explicit cast because the compiler doesn't know at compile time that the `Length1` reference actually is a `Length2`. But what you are trying to do is not possible, since `Length1` IS NOT A `Length2`.

It's like saying that `Car extends Vehicle`. You can always point to a `Car` and say `Car`.

```
Car c = new Car();
```

It's always OK. And you can always point to one and say `Vehicle`:

```
Vehicle v = new Car();
```

No problem. The only problem you'll have here is if you decide to call, say, the `printLicensePlate()` method of `Car` which doesn't exist in Vehicle, which has a melhod called `printSpeed()`. Since a `Car` IS A `Vehicle, you can always call:

```
c.printSpeed();
c.printLicensePlate();
```

and

```
v.printSpeed();
```

But you can't call:

```
v.printLicensePlate();
```

even though you know that `v` is a `Car`. This is the case where you use a cast, to convert the reference. This is illegal:

```
c = v; // WRONG
```

because the at *compile time* we don't know what's really in `c`, since `new Car()` only happens at *runtime*. So you tell the compiler "trust me, this is really a `Car`" by doing:

```
c = (Car) v;
```

But what you did was something like:

```
Car c = new Vehicle(); // WRONG
```

You pointed to a generic `Vehicle` and said `Car`. While a `Car` is always a `Vehicle`, a `Vehicle` may not be a car. (Using the `c` reference, the compiler believes you can legally call `c.printLicensePlate()`, but at runtime the object you find has no such method. So even if you could pass this by the compiler by casting the reference, it wouldn't work and would produce a `ClassCastException` at runtime.)

Answer (score 0):

Like Leo said, if L1 is the super type of L2, that implies L2 has all of L1 and then some. So if you try to create an L2 from an L1, information will be missing.

Comment: Would you also recommend a casting method that would fill in the missing info when assigning L2 = L1?

Comment: @Ktmock13 - there is no such magic "casting method".  The best way to do it is to write code to copy the fields ... by hand.

Comment: You've created a `Length1` when you said `c = new Length1()`.  This object will always be a `Length1`, forever, until it's destroyed.  Therefore, if you want a `Length2` object, you have to create a new object.

Comment: You could create a constructor that takes in an object of L1, and assigns the appropriate fields from L1 to the new L2. You would have to do this by hand though.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is no, you can't unfortunately. But you can try to push all useful information from L1 into L2 using some method like L2 = L2.valueOf(L1) that copies all the known fields from L1 into L2, leaving the missing ones empty. You have to write this method by hand. Maybe you can save some time reusing some L1 constructor in L2.